# How do I know if an application has been installed and how to uninstall it?

Tags: 18.04, installed-programs

So I installed the kite package through atom but after reading some things I changed my mind. When I search my computer the kite application is there but when I open kite it still asks for which editors I want to install it.

How do I know if I installed a program or just the installer for a program? And how do I delete it on their website it says I can run the following command `./.local/share/kite/uninstall` but when I do this it says there is no such directory or file. Inside my home directory there is a `.kite` folder though. Does the uninstall command maybe not work because I haven't finished the complete installation process?

Comment: The installation instructions for `kite` I found make no mention of how to uninstall it: https://pyrocko.org/kite/docs/current/installation.html

Comment: if you're using this way to [install](https://kite.com/linux/) it, you can use [uninstall](https://help.kite.com/article/62-managing-editor-plugins) from this way :):):)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix at the bottom of the website https://help.kite.com/article/68-how-to-uninstall-kite

Comment: ~/.local/share/kite/uninstall 
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

open terminal window and type 'apt show ("application name")' and see if it has been installed... if so type 'apt remove ("appl. name")' to remove it. To reinstall it or to install any other program type 'apt install ("appl. name"). See also 'man apt' or 'apt help'

Comment: first: sudo apt update (give adm passwd); then sudo apt show '(application-name)'